# Get object property using variable in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get an object value using a variable passed to a function. Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```php
function get_date($object, $date_name)
{
    // this should execute like "$project->date_of_project"
    return formatted_date($object->$date_name);
}

echo get_date($project, 'date_of_project');
```

I am getting this warning (however the date does show up):

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I read in a few places to try the following (but it does not work):

```php
$object->{$date_name}[0]
```

A `var_dump` shows the property is there:

```
object(stdClass)#33 (1) {
    ["date_of_project"]=>
    string(19) "2013-04-25 00:00:00"
}
```

**Update:** Here is a [**screenshot**](http://d.pr/i/9aNt) of the warning. You can see the date works, but the warning persists. Line 53 is the line with my `$object->$date_name`.

Comment: Make sure that `$project` (the parameter you are passing) has that property

Comment: What does `var_dump($object)` show (inside `get_date`)?

Comment: @RocketHazmat it shows the object and begins with `object(stdClass)` and it DOES include the date property.

Comment: And what does `formatted_date` look like? Maybe it cause the problem?

Comment: Please check the output of `var_dump` as suggested by @RocketHazmat because otherwise, there is no error in code. [Here](http://codepad.org/P1QMfMdL) is a SSCCE

Comment: To be certain its an object you should test the `var_dump` inside the get_date function.

Comment: I can confirm it is an object. Please see my updated answer. Also the date is working I still get the error though.

Comment: Where do you get this error?  Which line?  Your code works for me: http://codepad.org/wiAOMPSA  What's `formatted_date`?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the warning. You can see the date works, but the warning persists http://d.pr/i/9aNt Line 53 is the line with my `$object->$date`

Comment: @doitlikejustin: If the date is shown, then `$object->$date_name` clearly isn't the issue.  Is that really line 53 in the file shown?

Comment: @RocketHazmat this is my actual line http://d.pr/i/WIIk And I see your example, and if I copy/paste it into a new file on my system it does work. So something else must be the issue.

Comment: I know you have confirmed that `$object` is an object.. but what if you try converting `$object` to an object before the `formatted_date` call? `$object = (object) $object`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct, but $project is not an object. How do you initialize $project?

Comment: `$project` IS an object

Comment: either that, but than your php compiler fails, or you're worng.  please var_dump it or show your initialization

Comment: It doesn't fail, it's a warning. And a `var_dump` returns the `object(stdClass)` so I am not wrong, I know it is an object because I am accessing it in other places.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to type cast the variable like you do in other languages I know in c# i have to define the variable, it can be like

function get_date(Project $object, DateTime date)
 { .... }

maybe there is something similar in php.

also make sure that the property exists,I have experienced with php is that you can create variables on the fly this can be a good thing or a bad thing

also there is a difference with 'var' and "var" if i remember correctly